# Not able to send mail via Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I'm having a Ubuntu VPs with zpanel isntalled on it. There is something wrong going with the mail. Im not not able to receive the mails from my contact form on my wordpress site ( the site is hosted on the same server)

Here is the mail log:

```
Apr 13 06:41:10 localhost postfix/pickup[22315]: E2A544249F: uid=0 from=<root>

Apr 13 06:41:10 localhost postfix/cleanup[22851]: E2A544249F: message-id=<20140413104110.E2A544249F@localhost>

Apr 13 06:41:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: E2A544249F: from=<root@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=922, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 06:41:10 localhost postfix/local[22853]: E2A544249F: to=<root@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.$

Apr 13 06:41:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: E2A544249F: removed

Apr 13 07:03:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: A987B424B1: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=1185, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 07:03:18 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 07:03:48 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.78.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 07:03:48 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 07:04:18 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 07:04:48 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 07:04:48 localhost postfix/smtp[22915]: A987B424B1: to=<idviveka@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=397631, delays=397541/0.02/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (conn$

Apr 13 07:23:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: EFAB1424BC: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=420, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 07:23:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23284]: connect to mx.zohomail.com[72.5.230.114]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 07:24:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23284]: connect to mx2.zohomail.com[74.201.154.202]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 07:24:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23284]: EFAB1424BC: to=<hello@paleo-britain.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=172638, delays=172578/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferre$

Apr 13 08:13:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: A987B424B1: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=1185, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 08:13:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 08:13:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.78.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 08:14:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 08:14:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 08:14:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.26]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 08:14:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23502]: A987B424B1: to=<idviveka@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=401831, delays=401741/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (conn$

Apr 13 08:33:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: EFAB1424BC: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=420, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 08:33:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23554]: connect to mx.zohomail.com[72.5.230.114]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 08:34:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23554]: connect to mx2.zohomail.com[74.201.154.202]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 08:34:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23554]: EFAB1424BC: to=<hello@paleo-britain.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=176839, delays=176779/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferre$

Apr 13 09:23:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: A987B424B1: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=1185, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 09:23:19 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 09:23:49 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.78.27]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 09:24:19 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 09:24:19 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable

Apr 13 09:24:49 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.27]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 09:24:49 localhost postfix/smtp[23777]: A987B424B1: to=<idviveka@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=406032, delays=405941/0.02/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (conn$

Apr 13 09:43:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[7371]: EFAB1424BC: from=<www-data@www.paleo-britain.co.uk>, size=420, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 13 09:43:48 localhost postfix/smtp[23864]: connect to mx.zohomail.com[72.5.230.114]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 09:44:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23864]: connect to mx2.zohomail.com[74.201.154.202]:25: Connection timed out

Apr 13 09:44:18 localhost postfix/smtp[23864]: EFAB1424BC: to=<hello@paleo-britain.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=181039, delays=180978/0.03/61/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferre$

Apr 13 10:17:25 localhost postfix/smtpd[24005]: connect from unknown[218.59.209.142]
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Looks like a network issue and this has nothing to do with postfix.

Comment: Can you please brief me on this ?

When I try to ping some other server from this one it works perfectly. A few days back I got a main from my service provider that my IP has been listed in CBL ( central blocking list) due to spam. I got it delisted from there, but still no luck. It was working perfectly in the begining.

Answer (score 0):

- Getting listed in an `RBL` is not the end of the world. Not all mail service providers use all `RBL`s. Everyone have their own mechanisms to keep the abusers away.
- Even if your IP is in some mail providers abuse list, not all block/drop your connections. Some will accept your connection and provide some error code and an URL (`AOL` for example) for you to fix abuse from your server.

  ```
  421 4.7.1 : (DYN:T1) http://postmaster.info.aol.com/errors/421dynt1.html
  ```
- Also check the firewall rules on your server. Ensure that your service provider doesn't have any restrictions for outbound traffic on port 25

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the firewall and outbound traffic on the server. Still no luck :(